# Facing performance issue in Hazelcast with Client-Server

Tags: java, performance, kubernetes, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am facing performance issues with hazelcast configured as client-server.
I have one K8S Cluster consisting of 5 Nodes and 1 Master Node. Each node is of 64 GB of RAM and 16 Core (Hazelcast Version 3.12.4)
Hazelcast server is deployed on K8S with one POD on one of the nodes available in cluster
My Client is deployed on K8S which is connected to above Hazelcast with smart client (Hazelcast discovery enabled for K8S). There are a total 10 PODs of my applications with each node consisting of 2 PODs of my application.

I am running different different APIs and performing load testing of my application (Approx 110 Threads at a time shared across all 10 PODs)

I am having the following piece of code in my application to get cache.

```
public Map<Object, Object> get(String cacheId, Long lTenantId) {
     String strMethodName="get";
     long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
     Map<Object,Object> cacheDataMap=hazelcastInstance.getMap(cacheId);
     long totalTimeTaken = (System.currentTimeMillis()-t1);
     if(totalTimeTaken > 10){
         logger.warnLog(CLASSNAME, strMethodName,"Total time taken by "+cacheId+" identifier for get operation is : "+totalTimeTaken+" ms");
      }
      return cacheDataMap;
}
```

The way my application uses this map varies like

1)

```
map.get(key);
```

2)

```
Set keys = map.keySet();
   Iterator iterator = keys.iterator(); //I changed to keyset iterator because entryset was causing lot of performance issues
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      // doing stuff
   }
```

When all My APIs are started for Load I am getting these logs printed in an application (Total time taken by....) where each cache access time is > 10 miliseconds and this is causing performance issues and hence I am not able to achieve my desired TPS for all APIs.

There are approx 300 Maps are stored in cache where total size of the cache is 4.22 MB

I am using near cache configuration and also on the management center it is showing effectiveness as 100%. (This was taken when hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled was enabled).

I have also tried with 8 PODs deployed on 4 Nodes and 1 dedicated node for Hazelcast server but the issue remains the same. There are no issues observed when I am connecting Hazelcast as embedded and I am able to achieve my desired TPS for all APIs.

Am I Missing any configuration or any other thing which is causing this problem?

Here is my hazelcast-client.xml

```
<hazelcast-client
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
                  http://hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.11.xsd">

<group>
<name>dev</name>
</group>
<instance-name>hazelcast</instance-name>
<properties>
<property name="hazelcast.client.shuffle.member.list">true</property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">600000</property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval">180000</property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.event.queue.capacity">1000000</property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds">120</property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled">false</property>
<property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
<property name="hazelcast.map.invalidation.batch.enabled">false</property>
</properties>

<network>
<discovery-strategies>
<discovery-strategy enabled="true"
class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
<properties>
<property name="service-name"><service-name></property>
<property name="namespace"><namespace></property>
</properties>
</discovery-strategy>
</discovery-strategies>
<smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
<redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
<connection-timeout>90000</connection-timeout>
<connection-attempt-period>100</connection-attempt-period>
<connection-attempt-limit>0</connection-attempt-limit>

</network>

<near-cache name="default">
                <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
                <serialize-keys>true</serialize-keys>
                <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
                <eviction eviction-policy="NONE" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT"/>
        </near-cache>
</hazelcast-client>
```

Here is my hazelcast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.11.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <management-center enabled="${hazelcast.mancenter.enabled}">${hazelcast.mancenter.url}</management-center>

</hazelcast>
```

Comment: Could you try to start multiple Hazelcast members as the server part and check if the issue remains?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Tried with 3, 4 and  5 Hazelcast members as server, But couldn't achieve my desired TPS. It is pretty much same as it was with Single POD.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a cache is to get the value from a key as fast as possible. In general, you already have the key, and request the value. That means you send a request to any node, this looks in the partition table which partition the key belongs to, and forwards the query to the relevant node.

In your second use-case, you try to get all keys from all nodes:

```
Set keys = map.keySet();
Iterator iterator = keys.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    // doing stuff
}
```

To return fast as possible, Hazelcast will return a lazy implementation of the `Iterator`. For each call to `next()`, it will need first to retrieve the key following the above process. Plus, I assume the `// doing stuff` code actually loads the value from the key.

In conclusion, please avoid at all costs using `map.keySet()`. Unless I know more about your context and your use-case, I unfortunately cannot provide with a relevant alternative.

Comment: Yes // doing stuff in this block i access values of each item of the cache.
There are caches which I can't access via it's key and have to iterate through all the values until I find my match.

Comment: Help me help you: please give more context. Otherwise, there's a high chance another alternative can solve your problem. Why can't you access the cache through the key?

Comment: Do you see all Hazelcast servers connecting and forming the cluster successfully? You can confirm that from members list in any of the servers' logs. Subsequently, can you also confirm that your client connects to all servers in the cluster? Again, you can check this in client's console logs.

Comment: @Nicolas For e.g. I have a cache called STAFF_CACHE, This cache contains key as Staff Id, Now all My APIs can accept either staff username or staff Id as input parameter. If in API I pass staff ID I can access directly via key, If username is passed then I need to iterate through cache to find my staff. There are lot of scenarios of similar kind. I do not want to create another cache with key as staff username and duplicate data.

Comment: @wildnez Yes I can see all client members are connected in logs as well as in management center. Also all Hazelcast servers are also in cluster verified from Hazelcast logs.

Comment: @PavanMulani I'm afraid there's no magical solution. Either you accept to duplicate your cache, or you keep your performance issue. A way in the middle would be to keep the mapping between the Staff Name and the Staff ID in a dedicated map.

Comment: @Nicolas Can Predicates help in this situation? Will it help in performance? Here in one of the article it is mentioned https://www.tothenew.com/blog/hazelcast-object-deserialization-with-distributed-query/
Also <read-backup-data>true</read-backup-data> can help in performance as mentioned here https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/#enabling-backup-reads

Comment: As I mentioned, nothing can help if you want to iterate through all the keys. If you need to access your data by 2 different keys, the "best" (less worst) solution is to have another map that maps name to ID as I've written above. Then, in order to avoid an additional network hop, you can create an `EntryProcessor` that will manage getting the ID then the value in a single block.

Comment: @PavanMulani when using a plain `keySet()` then applying filtering on the client side you are effectively copying the whole map over the network. Instead, you can query your `IMap` for data by matching on your objects' attributes using `IMap#values(Predicate)`, `IMap#keySet(Predicate)` or `IMap#entrySet(Predicate)`. Using these methods, filtering occurs on the server-side so you avoid the serialization and network overheads you are incurred to due.

Comment: @PavanMulani please see this gist for example code and more info about predicates and indexes: https://gist.github.com/vbekiaris/3c0586b8d6cd1e4d843b6d9cd33b0308  (the previous comment was published too early by mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get my performance with some tweak. I had common code to put data into cache and access data from cache. What I did is before putting data into final map, I added one more dummy key "ALL". So when My data is being access I always retrieve data from ALL key and then iterate over it. Though it is not a proper solution but managed to save lot of efforts. Posting this as an answer, might be useful for others who are in same situation.

Thanks all for sparing time and helping me out for possible options.